# How to unlock with face recognition for multiple users?

Tags: face-unlock

We are using our tablet together with my wife. I have added another user profile to the Android tablet (Samsung Tab A7, Android 10). I have switched to her account and we added her face for the recognition.

Question: is there a way to directly unlock the device with either of our faces? Otherwise the experience is awful. I need to turn on the device, click on the profile icon on the top right, catch the correct user in 1 second (otherwise screen turns off), then do the face recognition.

Comment: Upvoted.  That is *awful* OOBE/UX.

Comment: AFAIK, Android doesn't offer an integrated lock screen. There have been questions asked in the past about unlocking an existing user so long as the corresponding correct PIN/Password/Pattern was entered. The solutions are absent for them too.